# If someone blocks my number on their iPhone, can I still iMessage them through a linked email on my Messages app on macbook?

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

So basically, my sister blocked me on her iPhone (iOS8) because she's being immature and I really need her to read my message. If I iMessage her through my Messages app, and start the conversation from one of my linked e-mails, will it go through to her? I just don't know if when someone blocks an iPhone number, it automatically blocks all linked accounts... I kind of feel like it's not that advanced.

If anyone knows, could you please let me know? Thanks!

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't she just block that one as well?

Comment: I don't think it does, but I'm not sure. Maybe you have a buddy with iMessage to try out? Let him block your number and try sending him a message via the mailaddress